# Why isn't my Session Variable working?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I've checked for the normal stuff like white space before the php tags, and having a session_start() but cannot work this out for the life of me. I'm making a log in system for a client, so this is vital stuff.

Essentially, once I get to the second page $_SESSION['username']; is empty.
I've printed it out and its empty, but atm is activates the header re-direct which you can see in the code.

Thanks in advance for any help received :)

Relevant Code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include '../resources/methods/Library.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    //User already logged in!
    header('Location: Index.php');
}

//Username and password submitted by user
$usernameSubmitted = $_POST['username'];
$passwordSubmitted = $_POST['password'];

if($usernameSubmitted != "" && $passwordSubmitted != "")
{
    //User has entered both a username and a password. We shall validate them

    //Connect to database and select all the admin accounts
    connectToDB();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM admins" or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $numberOfAdmins = mysql_num_rows($data) or die(mysql_error());


    //Check if the username corresponds to any found in the database                        
    $usernameValid = false;

    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfAdmins; $i++)
    {
        if($usernameSubmitted == mysql_result($data, $i, "Username"))
        {
            $userToLogInAs = $i;
            $usernameValid = true;
        }
    }

    //If username is valid, check password
    if($usernameValid != false)
    {
        //Passwords are held as blowfish encryptions for security. Encypt this so we can compare
        $encryptedPasswordSubmitted = crypt($passwordSubmitted, '$2a$07$buzzybees5hivestottenhoe$');

        if($encryptedPasswordSubmitted == mysql_result($data, $userToLogInAs, "Password"))
        {
            //Create a session variable so the user remains logged in
            $_SESSION['username'] = $usernameSubmitted;

            //User entered the correct username and password, redirect them to the website.
            header('Location: Index.php');
        }
    }

    //If we've got this far then the user didn't authenticate successfully.
    $message = "<h2>Sorry, Invalid Credentials</h2><p>Check that you're tying your username and password correctly.</p>";
}
```

?>

And the next page:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    //User not signed in, send them to the log in page
    header('Location: Log-In.php');
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: what do you mean it's not working?

Comment: Can you actually tell us why it is not working. Error Messages? What is happening that is unexpected?

Comment: Such an amateur mistake to not include why its broken, added that in.

Comment: Why not bind to select only the row with a matching user name?

Comment: Yes, I have used exit('test') and I get to and execute said branch :)

cbuckley, rapid development. I just wanna get the thing working first then go back and add sanitization and stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but assuming that you are only showing part of the code of your login script:

You do not use `die()` after the redirect on a successful login, so any code that comes after that and that you have not shown here, gets executed. If you are manipulating the `$_SESSION` variable there, that could cause your problem.

To be safe, just change your code to:

```
    if($encryptedPasswordSubmitted == mysql_result($data, $userToLogInAs, "Password"))
    {
        //Create a session variable so the user remains logged in
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usernameSubmitted;

        //User entered the correct username and password, redirect them to the website.
        header('Location: Index.php');
        die();    // this is important!
    }
```

and see if that solves the problem. Note that you need to do that everywhere you redirect.